# mcufriend 2.4 TFT with ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, shields, tft

I have this TFT:

[image]

Now, the problem is, I will not use this as a shield (i.e. I will not just put it on top of an Arduino Uno). I will use it with an ESP8266 (NodeMCU). I want to know how to wire them up together. There is [this website](http://www.nihamkin.com/2016/03/04/connecting-esp8266-with-ili9341-tft-display/) (and a few more that say the same way). But the problem is I cannot find `SDI/MOSI` or `SDD/MISO` on the TFT above.

Comment: I also want to program mcufriend 2.4 TFT with ESP8266 did you try it and did it work? can you give me any information? (Library, connection between mcufriend 2.4 TFT and ESP8266)

Comment: interessting, did it work on NodeMCU?

Answer (score 3):

You have an 8-bit parallel interface TFT display. It requires 13 GPIO pins - D0-D7 plus reset, chip select, read, write and register select. You can forego the "read" signal and tie it high to save a pin. You can probably do the same with the reset signal, meaning you need a minimum of 11 pins.

I am not sure the NodeMCU has that many available, does it? (maybe it does, I don't have one to hand right now), so you may want to try getting it going with an SPI or I2C IO expander (though slowly).

And then of course you have to find the right library for the chip on the display (there's a few it could be - I have seen at least 3 different ones on the same, or similar, carrier PCB) that works with the NodeMCU.

Answer (score 3):

SD_DI is the MOSI, and SD_DO is the MISO. According to the datasheet.